# Equivalent of PostGIS' ST_Project on the perfect sphere

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a PostGIS geography point that I want to rotate by a set distance on the ideal sphere (not spheroid).  I see the ST_Project() function, but it seems that it rotates points on the spheroid.  For example, if I rotate (0,10) by 1 degree north, the result is slightly larger than 1 degree

```
select ST_AsText(ST_Project(ST_Point(0,10), 111194.68229846345*1,radians(0.0)));

   st_astext         
---------------------------
 POINT(0 11.0052750273178)
(1 row)
```

Rotating (0,60) by the same distance gives a result that is slightly less than 1 degree.

```
POINT(0 60.9979713953998)
```

I can also compute the distance between the points using the spheroid

```
select ST_Distance(ST_Project(ST_Point(60,89.9)::geography, 111194.68229846345*1,radians(0.0)),ST_Point(60,89.9),'t');
    st_distance    
------------------
 111194.682298475
(1 row)
```

and the perfect sphere

```
select ST_Distance(ST_Project(ST_Point(60,89.9)::geography, 111194.68229846345*1,radians(0.0)),ST_Point(60,89.9),'f');
   st_distance   
-----------------
 110698.09475313
(1 row)
```

So it is not that I got the circumference of the Earth wrong.

For many functions that operate on geography objects, such as [ST_DWithin](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html), there is an option to use the spheroid or the perfect sphere.  I do not see the option for [ST_Project](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Project.html).

In general, my azimuth will be one of 0, 90, 180, and 270, and it has to work properly around the poles.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create a new spatial projection, where semi-major and semi-minor axes for the spheroid are the same. So for a sphere with a radius of 6370986 m, here is a new SRID=123456:

```
INSERT INTO spatial_ref_sys(srid, auth_name, srtext, proj4text)
VALUES (123456, NULL, '', '+proj=longlat +a=6370986 +b=6370986 +ellps=sphere +no_defs ');
```

For `geography` types, the default SRID=4326 is for the WGS84 ellipsoid. To use the new sphere ellipsoid, you need to set the SRID to a non-default value.

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_Project(ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(0,10), 123456), 111194.68229846345, 0.0));

  st_astext
-------------
 POINT(0 11)
(1 row)
```